# Keeping track of custom events in Google Analytics (React app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've been running into some difficulty with Google Analytics and keeping track of some custom events that I've made on a React app, using Firebase to handle GA. The event I'm trying to keep trying to keep track of is a string, that will be an "affiliate code" that customers will type in to be able to use the site. This project is for a client that wants to be able to see the total # of people that have entered in various affiliate codes.

So far, I've been able to create and log my custom events I've made, but I don't see any way to see the **totals** of them over time. I can see the recent codes sent in the last 30 min from the "realtime" page, but not over all time.

To log events, I made a helper function that calls the `logEvent()` method from `firebase/analytics`.

```
addEvent(eventName, parameters = undefined) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      logEvent(this.analytics, eventName, parameters);
    }
  }
```

In the specific instance of this affiliate code, this is how I'm calling it:

```
Firebase.addEvent("affiliate_code_entered", {
      affiliate_code: formattedVal,
    });
```

Does anyone know if there's something I can do to make sure I can see the totals of these affiliate codes entered? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can view the statistics about your events in the Firebase console under the [Events](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/analytics/events) tab. This dashboard shows the event reports that are created for each distinct type of event logged by your app. Though, you might not see it right away due to [Analytics data reporting delay](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up).